# understanding default constructor c++

Tags: c++, default-constructor

```
class WithCC { // With copy-constructor
public:
  // Explicit default constructor required:
  WithCC() {}
  WithCC(const WithCC&) {
    cout << "WithCC(WithCC&)" << endl;
  }
};

class WoCC { // Without copy-constructor
  string id;
public:
  WoCC(const string& ident = "") : id(ident) {}
  void print(const string& msg = "") const {
    if(msg.size() != 0) cout << msg << ": ";
    cout << id << endl;
  }
};

class Composite {
  WithCC withcc; // Embedded objects
  WoCC wocc;
public:
  Composite() : wocc("Composite()") {}
  void print(const string& msg = "") const {
    wocc.print(msg);
  }
};
```

I'm reading thinking in c++ chapter 11 default copy-constructor.
For the above code, the author said: "The class `WoCC` has no copy-constructor, but its constructor will store a message in an internal string that can be printed out using 
`print( )`.This constructor is explicitly called in `Composite’s` constructor initializer list".

Why the `WoCC` constrcutor must be explicitly called in `Composite`'s constructor?

Comment: `WoCC` does have a copy constructor.  Since you didn't declare one, it gets an *implicitly declared* copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can happily leave out the explicit construction because `wocc` will be implicitly default constructed. A default constructor is one that takes no arguments. `WoCC` has a default constructor because the constructor that takes a `string` has a default value for that string.

The constructor only needs to be called explicitly if you want to pass a specific string, as is happening in this case.

However, if the argument did not have a default value (remove `= ""`), then you would indeed have to explicitly call the correct constructor in `Composose`. That's because defining any of your own constructors stops the compiler from implicitly generating a defaulted default constructor. If it has no default constructor, then you need to make sure the correct one is called for the `wocc` member.

Also, `WoCC` does indeed have a copy constructor. The compiler generates an implicit copy constructor if you don't define one (and it only defines it as `delete`d if you provide a move constructor).